# Appium doesn´t work with Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, appium

I'm doing a Java test on an Android 4.4.2 device with Appium. When I try to use the `sendKeys` command with text boxes in the app, I get an error message like this: "NosuchElement". The same test works with a device with Android 5.1.

What can I do to perform the test on the 4.4.2 device? I have tried with Appium 1.6.4, and Appium 1.4.16.1. I also have tried making `.click` on the text boxes before the `sendKeys` command, but the issue persits.

Comment: "doesn't work" - how? Crash, compile error or just plain and simple doesn't show up?

Comment: The java test compiles, but when appium tries to access to the textboxes by they id propperty can´t find then, and the Intellij Idea ´s console shows the message "notSuchelement".

Comment: Is the view inflated before you try to access the id?

Comment: Yes. The application is loaded on the device. The problem starts when loooking for the textboxes ´ids.

Comment: Do the textboxes exist?

Comment: Yes. In fact the tests works ok with a device with android 5.1.1